# array projection with findandmodify

Tags: mongodb

I'm using findAndModify command to maintain a list of undo/redo commands. I'm using "fields" tag to specify what the "before" values were. This is then used to build undo command. ie:

cmd:

```
{
    findAndModify : "aaa",
    query : { _id: ObjectId('5215f7d1fe789bb17427bde9') },
    update : { "$set" : { "v1" : 200 } },
    fields : {  v1 : 1, _id : 0 }
}
```

built result:

```
"Do" : { "$set" : { "v1" : 200 } },
"Undo" : { "$set" : { v1" : 100 } }
```

However, I cannot make this work for arrays. I do a set command like this:

```
{ $set : "myArrayVar.3" : 100 }
```

I've tried using projections like:

```
{ "myArrayVar.3" : 1 }
{ "myArrayVar.$" : 1 }
```

but both return just empty array braces:

```
{ myArrayVar : [] }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @Discipol yes, field myArrayVar exists and is an actual array.

Comment: @Discipol as for id projection: [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#read-operations-projection) _Important The _id field is, by default, included in the result set. To exclude the _id field from the result set, you need to specify in the projection document the exclusion of the _id field (i.e. { _id: 0 })._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use numeric array indexes in projections, but you can use [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/#proj._S_slice) instead:

```js
fields: { myArrayVar: { $slice: [2, 1] } }
```

That would include just the third element (skip 2, take 1).

Comment: Thanks, slice does work. However, there's another issue I stumbled upon. The projection is now returning all other fields also. I assume since there is no "fieldname : 1" operator. Any ideas how to combine these two operators?

Comment: You can exclude the fields you don't want by adding `fieldname: 0` properties to `fields`.

Comment: Yeah, exclusion does make it work, but as it seems, if you provide one "fieldname : 1", all others (except id) are disabled by default. But when using slice with array, I don't know how to specify only array. I'd really love to avoid setting all other fields to 0, just to handle this case.

Comment: Agreed.  Sure seems like a bug the way including `$slice` is treated differently from other projections.

Comment: Well, I tried this and it seems to give me what I wanted.

fields: { myArrayVar : { $slice : [2,1] }, myArrayVar : 1, _id : 0 }

Comment: Partially at least
{ "myArrarVar" : [ 100 ] }
Any ideas how to return array index whose value was changed?